# Applying neumann boundary conditions to the diffusion equation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, numerical-methods

I've plotted a code for the the numerical solution to the diffusion equation du/dt=D(d^2 u/dx^2) + Cu where u is a function of x and t - I've solved it numerically and plotted it with the direchtlet boundary conditions u(-L/2,t)=u(L/2,t)=0, with the critical length being the value before the function blows up exponentially, which I have worked out to be pi. I'm trying to change the right boundary condition to be the Neumann boundary condition u_x(L/2)=0 which should decrease the critical length and cause the function to increase exponentially, but I'm not too sure exactly how to do this and mine doesn't seem to work quite right - could someone see if they could identify where I've gone wrong? Thanks!

```
L=np.pi # value chosen for the critical length
s=101 # number of steps in x
t=10002 # number of timesteps
ds=L/(s-1) # step in x
dt=0.0001 # time step
D=1 # diffusion constant, set equal to 1
C=1 # creation rate of neutrons, set equal to 1
Alpha=(D*dt)/(ds*ds) # constant for diffusion term
Beta=C*dt # constant for u term

x = np.linspace(-L/2, 0, num=51)
x = np.concatenate([x, np.linspace(x[-1] - x[-2], L/2, num=50)]) # setting x in the specified interval

u=np.zeros(shape=(s,t))
u[50,0]=1/ds # delta function
for k in range(0,t-1):
    u[0,k]=0 #direchtlet boundary condition
    for i in range(1,s-1):
        u[i,k+1]=(1+Beta-2*Alpha)*u[i,k]+Alpha*u[i+1,k]+Alpha*u[i-1,k] # numerical solution 
    u[s-1,k+1]=u[s-2,k+1] # neumann boundary condition
    if k == 50 or k == 100 or k == 250 or k == 500 or k == 1000 or k == 10000: # plotting at times
        plt.plot(x,u[:,k])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you referring to the curve in your plot for last `k`, i.e., `k=10000` where the curve is not zero on the right hand side? Please explain more clearly

Comment: As per your question, all you need to do is to use `u[s-1,k+1] = 0` instead of `u[s-1,k+1]=u[s-2,k+1]`

Comment: Sorry, basically I think the curve should increase exponentially as time increases with this plot but it doesn't seem to do that at all.

Comment: I tried using 'u[s-1,k+1] = 0' before, but it doesn't change the graph at all from if there was no boundary condition.

Comment: I used `u[s-1,k+1] = 0` and got a different curve for last k where the right edge of the curve is at 0

Comment: It doesn't seem to change the graph for me than if I use the original boundary conditions of u[0,k]=0 and u[s-1,k]=0 - the original boundary conditions should produce a regular plot for the diffusion equation but if I change it it should cause the critical length of the graph to decrease and cause it to increase exponentially.

Comment: I don't know but it worked for me when using both the conditions. Make sure you use the `u[s-1,k]=0` condition after this line : `for i in range(1,s-1):`

Comment: Does it increase exponentially over time? Mine just diffuses, I'm trying to see if there's another part of my code which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to apply **both** left and right boundary conditions at the start of your time loop and for the current time step (not at `k+1` as you are doing on the right BC).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
L=np.pi # value chosen for the critical length
s=101 # number of steps in x
t=10002 # number of timesteps
ds=L/(s-1) # step in x
dt=0.0001 # time step
D=1 # diffusion constant, set equal to 1
C=1 # creation rate of neutrons, set equal to 1
Alpha=(D*dt)/(ds*ds) # constant for diffusion term
Beta=C*dt # constant for u term

x = np.linspace(-L/2, 0, num=51)
x = np.concatenate([x, np.linspace(x[-1] - x[-2], L/2, num=50)]) # setting x in the specified interval

u=np.zeros(shape=(s,t))
u[50,0]=1/ds # delta function
for k in range(0,t-1):
    u[0,k] = 0 # left direchtlet boundary condition
    u[s-1,k] = 0 # right dirichlet boundary condition

    for i in range(1,s-1):
        u[i,k+1]=(1+Beta-2*Alpha)*u[i,k]+Alpha*u[i+1,k]+Alpha*u[i-1,k] # numerical solution 
    if k == 50 or k == 100 or k == 250 or k == 500 or k == 1000 or k == 10000: # plotting at times
        plt.plot(x,u[:,k])

plt.savefig('test1.png')
plt.close()
```

For the dirichlet BC you get: 
[image]
(probably same as before since for a diffusion problem it won't make a lot of difference, but was incorrect anyways). Then you change you right boundary condition forthe Von-Neumann BC

```
u[s-1,k] = u[s-3,k] # right von-neumann boundary condition
```

since I see that you are using a central difference scheme so the Von-Neumann BC states that du/dx=0 at the boundary. Discretising this derivative with the central difference scheme at the right boundary is `(u[s-1,k]-u[s-3,k])/dx = 0`, so `u[s-1,k]=u[s-3,k]`. With this change you get
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry to take on another question, but the graph should also experience something similar if I were to increase L (since above a critical length of L the graph increases exponentially), but mine doesn't seem to change either really - do you know if there is something wrong with how I've defined x?

Comment: `L` is just the spatial domain. What do you mean by "since above a critical length of L the graph increases exponentially"? If you increase your domain the function will take more time to reach the boundaries and these to have any effect on the soltuino really.

Comment: When I used the initial Dirichlet boundary conditions to solve the function analytically I got that L=pi, which is the value at which beyond the function breaks and increases exponentially. I'm not sure if my numerical solution really takes this into consideration.

Comment: what do you mean you got L=pi? You get an analytical soltuion defined in your domain, nothing else right?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I got told to "Solve the equation above over the interval, −L/2 ≤ x ≤L/2, subject to the following boundary conditions: u( −L/2,t)= 0 and u(L/2,t) = 0. Analytically determine the critical length of the system (C, D = 1.0), beyond which always leads to an exponentially increasing solution". I got that it's L=pi, so surely in my code if I change it to L=2pi it should start increasing?This might be more of a question for the maths stack exchange, sorry!